# How can I SELECT DISTINCT on the last, non-numerical part of a mixed alphanumeric field?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I have a data set that looks something like this:

```
A6177PE
A85506
A51SAIO
A7918F
A810004
A11483ON
A5579B
A89903
A104F
A9982
A8574
A8700F
```

And I need to find all the ENDings where they are non-numeric. In this example, that means PE, AIO, F, ON, B and F.

In pseudocode, I'm imagining I need something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM 
  (SELECT SUBSTR(COL,[SOME_CLEVER_LOGIC]) AS X FROM TABLE);
```

Any ideas? Can I solve this without learning regexp?

EDIT: To clarify, my data set is a lot larger than this example. Also, I'm only interested in the part of the string AFTER the numeric part. If the string is "A6177PE" I want "PE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col,INSTR(TRANSLATE(col,'A0123456789','A..........'),'.',-1)+1)
  FROM table;
```

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't know Oracle SQL. But, I think something like this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X FROM 
  (SELECT SUBSTR(COL,REGEXP_INSTR(COL, "[[:ALPHA:]]+$")) AS X FROM TABLE);
```

REGEXP_INSTR(COL, "[[:ALPHA:]]+$") should return the position of the first of the characters at the end of the field.

Answer (score 2):

For readability, I'd recommend using the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) function (If there are no performance issues of course, as this is definitely slower than the accepted solution).

> ...also similar to REGEXP_INSTR, but instead of returning the position of the substring, it returns the substring itself

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR(MY_COLUMN,REGEXP_SUBSTR("[a-zA-Z]+$")) FROM MY_TABLE;
```

(:alpha: is supported also, as @Audun wrote )

Also useful: [Oracle Regexp Support (beginning page)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix.htm#g693775)